# Can cesium move 5000 objects?

Tags: cesiumjs

I tried to enhance the [czml example](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML.html&label=Showcases) to move 100, 500 and 1000 objects instead of few by adding loop into the built-in czml code, and the map was stucked after 1000 objects. I saw the lots-of-satellites too, but I think that there are just few hundrends. If cesium doesn't have the means to do that, how can I enhance it to add fast layer of my own ? Is there any way to combine three.js for this enhancement ? 
The result has to look something like [this](http://webgl-test.site11.com/webgl-test-master/).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, yes, Cesium can handle 5000 objects.  The largest single Cesium app I have personally worked on involved over 35,000 time-dynamic objects.

The full answer is a little more involved.  If all you are talking about is Billboard rendering, 5000 is easy.  If you want to involve more complex types of visualization, with lots of dynamic geometry and polylines, then it can get a little more complicated.  It also depends on the browser and CPU/GPU requirements that you are targeting.  Some aspects of Cesium are currently CPU bound, while other things (such as static geometry) are GPU bound.  Chrome beats Firefox hands-down in the performance department.  Furthermore, it's really easy to write slow JavaScript code, so if you run into problems it's important to use the profiler (the one included with Chrome is great) to pinpoint exactly where the app is spending most of its time (it may not be Cesium).

Cesium developers are always on the lookout to improve performance and there's actually a lot of work being done in the CZML & DynamicScene area right now.  If you run into a specific bottleneck that you are having trouble getting past, we'd be happy to help point you in the right direction.